# Can't install canvas-sketch

Tags: canvas, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install canvas-sketch with this command in the terminal:

npm install canvas-sketch-cli -g

I'm on mac / mojave and my user is in admin.
And i have node.js v16.14.0
And npm 8.3.1

But i got plenty of error and i'm not an expert at all so i'm lost.

Can you help me ?

THANK'S A LOT

Here are the error :

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/canvas-sketch-cli/src/index.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/canvas-sketch
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/canvas-sketch-cli/src/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/canvas-sketch'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/canvas-sketch-cli/src/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/canvas-sketch'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/canvas-sketch-cli/src/index.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/canvas-sketch'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I used su root and then launch the command to install canvas-sketch and it seem to work. But i've still have Warnings, don't know if it's a big issue...

```
WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

[edit]Second problem, i can no longer use su root : i enter a correct password but i have this message : su: Sorry

[edit]
i try to install canvas-sketch-util  :
npm install canvas-sketch-util --save

But i get the sams error xhan i type "canvas-sketch sketch-02" or even "canvas-sketch hello.js --new" :

=> command not found

It's like i can run a canvas-sketch expression just once and after that it didn't work anymore...

Lost in translation :-/

Any ideas ?

Thank's

used su root and then launch the command to install canvas-sketch and it seem to work. But i've still have Warnings, don't know if it's a big issue...

```
WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

[edit] it works once but not anymore?! Know when i want to create this file : canvas-sketch hello.js --new I have this message : -bash: canvas-sketch: command not found

Second problem, i can no longer use su root : i enter a correct password but i have this message : su: Sorry

[edit again]

**canvas-sketch @ canvas-sketch-util
return > canvas-sketch: command not found**

Any ideas ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Just type sudo infront of the call:

sudo npm install canvas-sketch-cli -g

that worked for me.

all the best
a

Comment: THX for the reply but it dose not  work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried the sudo npm install canvas-sketch-cli -g line and it allowed me to input my password at least to bypass the issue, however it also let me know that of the 271 packages available, 56 were looking for funds and 2 had severe vulnerabilities... am having to run npm audit fix --force, hopefully this works... At least sudo allowed the password to be input.